# How can I create an alias for a generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax

How can I do the following in C#? What is the right way to write the first line of this code snippet?

```
using KVP<K, V> = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<K, V>;

class C { KVP<int, string> x; }
```

Comment: as Eric Lippert stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3720222/303290) "This is an occasionally requested feature." which hasn't made it into production yet.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't, basically. You can only use fixed aliases, such as:

```
using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>;

class C { Foo x; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can go with inheritance:

```
public class MyList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<IEnumerable<HashSet<T1>>, IComparable<T2>>> { }

public void Meth()
{
    var x = new MyList<int, bool>();
}
```

Though not in your particular case, as KeyValuePair is sealed :-(