# Using Statement with Generics: using ISet<> = System.Collections.Generic.ISet<>

Tags: c#, generics, syntax, alias, using

Since I am using two different generic collection namespaces (`System.Collections.Generic` and `Iesi.Collections.Generic`), I have conflicts.  In other parts of the project, I am using both the nunit and mstest framework, but qualify that when I call `Assert` I want to use the nunit version by

```
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;
```

Which works great, but I want to do the same thing with generic types.  However, the following lines do not work

```
using ISet = System.Collections.Generic.ISet;
using ISet<> = System.Collections.Generic.ISet<>;
```

Does anyone know how to tell .net how to use the using statement with generics?

Comment: This is an occasionally requested feature.  It's been on the list of possible features for a long time, but has never been high enough priority to actually implement.

Comment: Eric, this is the first time I've run across this issue, since the .net 4.0 framework added ISet<>, and the Iesi.Collections dll targets 3.5.  Usually other developers are good about not conflicting with the standard .net naming.

Comment: Why do you have it in two different namespaces?  Can you provide more information?

Comment: I'd phrase that differently. Intentionally using the same name for two different things is going to be inconvenient. This works best if you are extremely unlikely to be `using` the two namespaces simultaneously.

Comment: @EricLippert When converting code from Java or Haskell or other languages that supports precise symbol import (i.e. `import myModule.MyClass;` in Java, I found this is a major defect of C# because you have to `using` everything from `System.Collections.Generic` even when you only need `IEnumerable<>` for your LINQ expression. Java is not allow renaming but I think import renaming is is actually "occasionally" requested, not precise import/using.

Comment: And 14 years later, still the same...
Don't get me wrong I love lots of things in C#.
But last few years, I feel the direction has been wrong:
- new features not supported in .Net Frameworks
- new features complex and supporting code probably even more so
- simple stuff asked to declutter or improve performances always pushed down, another example is fixed array of structs that would benefit A LOT performance in many cases...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you're better off aliasing the namespaces themselves as opposed to the generic types (which I don't think is possible).

So for instance:

```
using S = System.Collections.Generic;
using I = Iesi.Collections.Generic;
```

Then for a BCL `ISet<int>`, for example:

```
S.ISet<int> integers = new S.HashSet<int>();
```

Comment: Very nice suggestion! Had the exact same problem just now and this did not immediately occur to me.

Comment: That only works if it's the namespace that's the long bit. If the type parameters themselves have lengthy type names, you're out of luck.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. I want to use constants defined in a generic class as default parameter values for a constructor and there are 4 of them, so I have to type the full, lengthy class name out, with it's generic parameters, plus the constant name. This could be solved if the language allowed using statements _inside_ the generic class, like `using C = Long.Name<TKey,TValue>`. Outside the class, the generic parameters are unkknown, so it's not useful.

Answer (score 53):

Unfortunately, the `using` directive does not do what you want.  You can say:

```
using Frob = System.String;
```

and

```
using ListOfInts = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>;
```

but you cannot say

```
using Blob<T> = System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

or

```
using Blob = System.Collections.Generic.List
```

It's a shortcoming of the language that has never been rectified.

Comment: What's the best way to lobby for this feature?

Comment: @miniBill: Try posting to the language design forum at Roslyn.codeplex.com.

Comment: There is a proposal [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1239). I too would love to have this feature.

Answer (score 7):

The only way you can alias a generic type is to specialize it as follows.

```
using IntSet = System.Collections.Generic.ISet<int>;
```

You can not alias an open generic type as you have done in your example:

```
using MySet = System.Collections.Generic.ISet<>;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I will be able to use this later!

Comment: Why does your first example won't compile on VS2017?

Answer (score 3):

Your alias name is the same as the class name itself, so you still have ambiguity, just as if you had a `using` for each namespace.  Give the alias of the class a *different* name, i.e.:

```
using FirstNamespace;
using OtherObject = SecondNamespace.MyObject;

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        MyObject first = new MyObject;//will be the MyObject from the first namespace
        OtherObject second = new OtherObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can go with inheritance:

```
public class MyList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<IEnumerable<HashSet<T1>>, IComparable<T2>>> { }

public void Meth()
{
    var x = new MyList<int, bool>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alias a class doing :

```
using Test = NameSpace.MyClass;
```

Only if the class is NOT generic.

Comment: You *can* alias a generic class, you just need to specify a concrete type in the alias, rather than leaving it generic.