# using Alias = Class; with generics

Tags: c#, generics, alias

In C# it is possible to alias classes using the following:

```
using Str = System.String;
```

Is this possible with classes that depend on generics, i have tried a similar approach but it does not seem to compile.

```
using IE<T> = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>;
```

and

```
using IE = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable;
```

Is this even possible using generics in C#? If so, what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720222/using-statement-with-generics-using-iset-system-collections-generic-iset can help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this possible with classes that depend on generics, i have tried a similar approach but it does not seem to compile.
>
> ```
> using IE<T> = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>;
> ```

No, this isn’t possible. The only thing that works is this:

```
 using IE = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>;
```

A `using` declaration cannot be generic.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), version 5, section 9.4.1 states:

> Using aliases can name a closed constructed type, but cannot name an
>   unbound generic type declaration without supplying type arguments. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> namespace N1
> {
>   class A<T>
>   {
>       class B {}
>   }
> }
> namespace N2
> {
>   using W = N1.A;         // Error, cannot name unbound generic type
>   using X = N1.A.B;           // Error, cannot name unbound generic type
>   using Y = N1.A<int>;        // Ok, can name closed constructed type
>   using Z<T> = N1.A<T>;   // Error, using alias cannot have type parameters
> }
> ```